# Associate a publication list with an email sent via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, api, publicationlist

I'm trying to send an **email** via **API**, but I really need to apply a **publication list**.

I know it's possible to do this using Journey Builder, but it would be much better if I could do **all the configuration via API**.
For example, creating a send definition via API and sending the email via API, also associating it to a publication list - it would be commercial and transactional sends.

I tried using Triggered Send, but it does now allow associating a publication list.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a publication list to an email definition might be possible by using a User-Initiated send.
User-initiated sends can be created and scheduled via the SOAP API.
The following document contains information about creating, performing, and deleting send definitions:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/creating_performing_and_deleting_email_send_definitions.html?q=user-initiated